# What is slave select signal on the APB bus for?

Tags: bus, addressing

I am currently working on an APB BFM and I have a question regarding the bus protocol. I understand every slave on APB bus has its own unique address space, where its internal registers are mapped. Why do we need the slave select signal then? Is it to save energy? Or am I wrong and each slave has an internal address map and their internal register addresses can overlap?

Answer (score 0):

P<sub>SEL</sub> is how the peripheral is selected for read or write operations. If P<sub>SEL</sub> is not asserted, the peripheral will ignore all bus activity. So it is a critical handshaking signal in order to implement the bus.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I ask is: if each slave has its own unique address space then what is the slave select signal for? Can't they just decode the address and see if they are being selected? Or do the slaves' address spaces overlap and the slave select is the only signal allowing them to tell the difference?

Comment: The address `P ADDR` can be up to 32 bits wide so `P SEL` is used to avoid constantly monitoring all 32 bits for the proper slave address